# Error 500 When trying to build PHP Switch from array

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am trying to make switches out of file names in a directory, so I don't have to add new switches each time I add new content... for example if file name is Domain_Hosting.php, I would like to make the switch/url ?op=Domain_hosting (minus the .php). The below script works up to the foreach statement, what am I doing wrong, please help

```
<?
require_once("C:/www/db.php");
stripslashes($_GET);
str_replace("%", '', $_GET);
$op = $_GET['op'];
$op = stripslashes($op);
$op = str_replace("/", '', $op);
$op = str_replace("%", '', $op);
$op = str_replace(".", '', $op);
$op = str_replace("+", '', $op);
$dir    = './includes/content/';

$files1 = scandir($dir, 1);

$files1 = array_map(function($e){
return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}, $files1);

switch($op) {

default:
require_once("includes/content/home.php");
break;

    foreach ($files1 as &$file) {
    case "$file":
    require_once("includes/content/$file.php")
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You cannot dynamically build `case` statements like that.  You're going to have to rethink your approach.

Comment: I rethought the above code and the issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
<?
require_once("C:/www/db.php");
stripslashes($_GET);
str_replace("%", '', $_GET);
$op = $_GET['op'];
$op = stripslashes($op);
$op = str_replace("/", '', $op);
$op = str_replace("%", '', $op);
$op = str_replace(".", '', $op);
$op = str_replace("+", '', $op);
$dir    = './includes/content/';

$files1 = scandir($dir, 1);

$files1 = array_map(function($e){
return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}, $files1);


if(count(files1)>0){
 foreach ($files1 as &$file) {
    require_once("includes/content/$file.php")
    }
}
else
require_once("includes/content/home.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seamed to work

```
require_once("C:/www/db.php");
stripslashes($_GET);
str_replace("%", '', $_GET);
$op = $_GET['op'];
$op = stripslashes($op);
$op = str_replace("/", '', $op);
$op = str_replace("%", '', $op);
$op = str_replace(".", '', $op);
$op = str_replace("+", '', $op);
$dir    = './includes/content/';

$files1 = scandir($dir, 1);

$files1 = array_map(function($e){
return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}, $files1);

if (!isset($op)) {
require_once("includes/content/home.php");
home();
}

if(isset($op)) {
  foreach ($files1 as &$file) {
    if( $op == $file){
    require_once("includes/content/$file.php");
     }
    }
}
```